# Change Django model column default using South

Tags: python, django, django-south

I'm using South with a Postgresql DB for a Django project.

There is a model field that I'd like to change the default value for going forward. I dont need previous records effected. Just new records.

Do I need to do a migration for this, or just change the model?

OLD FIELD DETAIL:

```
background_style = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BACKGROUND_STYLE, default=BackgroundStyleCode.CENTERED)
```

NEW FIELD DETAIL:

```
background_style = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BACKGROUND_STYLE, default=BackgroundStyleCode.STRETCHED)
```

(model name is "Page")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run a migration. Any time you make a change to a model, no matter how insignificant, you should create a schema migration so that you can move backwards and forwards to any point in time without any "magic" edits.

Comment: Django doesn't handle default values at the DB level.

Comment: You're correct. I removed the incorrect portion of my answer.

Comment: @Jordan When I run the migration ("python manage.py schemamigration page --auto"), it says "Nothing seems to have changed"

Comment: @Brenden: that's a shame that it does that. Well, as long as you're under source control, then you should be ok, although that's a bit disappointing that South doesn't keep track of that for you, even if there are no actual database changes.