# django model default value

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

a noob question here. I changed my model field from

`sale_rent = models.IntegerField(choices=sale_rent)` to

```
sale_rent = models.IntegerField(choices=sale_rent, default=-1)
```

After that I ran schemamigration using `South`, but I don't see any changes with `default` in my migrations file. Is default a Django level implementation? Using mysql with django 1.2.4.

Comment: Django doesn't handle default values at the DB level http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558148/change-django-model-column-default-using-south http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/db.add_column

Comment: great comment. put it as an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django doesn't handle default values at the DB level

[Change Django model column default using South](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558148/change-django-model-column-default-using-south)

http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/db.add_column